# Javascript - indexOf not so specific

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a way to lower the sensibility of the indexOf?
Like this

```
var arr = ["Hello", "stackoverflow"]
var idx = arr.indexOf("stack")
```

And get idx = 1 instead of idx = -1

Comment: @Joe : I guess he understands this,however he is looking for a method to match 'stack%'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to write your own function for that. Something like this would work:

```
function searchArr(arr, str) {
    for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if (arr[i].indexOf(str) !== -1) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
searchArr(arr, 'stack');// returns 1
```

That simply iterates through the array you enter as the first argument, and keeps going until it finds an index where the array's value at that index contains the search string.

Comment: What if none of the words in the array "match" the search term?

Comment: @Bergi then it completes the whole loop, and returns `undefined`. --- I've edited it so that it now returns -1 when it finds no matches.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was asking for, thanks (and +1) :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following will return an array of true and false showing which array elements match "stack".

```
var arr = ["Hello", "stackoverflow"];
var idx =arr.map(function(s) {return s.indexOf("stack") !== -1});
```

If simply want to check if a match exists, you could use

```
var arr = ["Hello", "stackoverflow"];
var matchFound =arr.some(function(s) {return s.indexOf("stack") !== -1});
```

Comment: Worth noting that this [doesn't work in IE8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Such an array is not exactly what the OP wanted, is it?

Comment: Unclear what he wants - the sample code seems to want both an array index and a position index.

Comment: For a check whether it exists, you should use `some` not `filter`.

Comment: @Joeytje50 in my opinion best practice is to use polyfill to compensate for this - polyfills can usually be found at MDN (your link is a good example). Seems the only logical way to benefit from new, native additions to Javascript.